# Hiding css files on WP

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there any way to hide css files on WP? I need to hide style.css file and file route.

Not only style but also need to hide other css file and their routes.

Comment: We might need a bit more information on this..

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "hide" and what you mean by "route"?

Comment: If it was possible to "hide" the stylesheet, how would peoples' browsers know where to find the styles? No...

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me...

Comment: you can hide your css for certain users, you hide appearance option on dashboard but to hide in general?, why people look for this... believe me you won't find an original CSS out there only original designs :P

Answer (score 1):

The fact is, any and all Style Rules are required to be either written directly to the document itself, or referenced in the head element in the form of a link tag.

There's no big secret to styling, so I'm not entirely certain why you would want to "hide" your stylesheet from prying eyes. Even if you were to create several hundred decoy CSS files and use cleverly placed @import rules to "confuse" somebody trying to find the actual filepath, what's to stop them from using a Web Inspector and seeing the active rules and the stylesheet in which they're contained?

Sorry to say, but you're pretty much going to have to deal with the fact that Style rules can be accessed by anybody.